# CSS-in-JS implementation that plays nice with DevTools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, styled-components, shadow-dom, css-in-js

Curious if anyone has any advice for a development workflow that doesn't breakdown a browser's DevTools ability for a UX Engineer to easily modify, manipulate and understand the CSS. I understand how CSS encapsulation is fantastic for React developers, but I find many implementations to be a complete dumpster fire when it comes to being able to systematically modify and enforce style systems for a team of developers simply because to tools to view the CSS are so obfuscated and the breadcrumb trail to match the styles with the elements is 10 times removed. Clearly it's an issue with these frameworks developing their own systems without any browser support, like a band-aid for future technologies.

The best solution I've found is ShadowDOM and I also hope and expect this to be the native standard of the future. I've looked with no results for a Chrome plugin to assist with this, but found nothing. Here is a simple example and you can see the CSS is pretty easy to find and understand -- but still a bit of a challenge to work with as it's fundamentally isolated in the DOM and hard to tell a style's scope.
http://react-shadow.herokuapp.com/

I've looked into JSS and a number of other helper builds. I'm currently trying to de-implement Styled-Components in our build as it seems to be the most obfuscated and convoluted of them all.

I believe the only options are:

1. Give Up, let the full stack developers fix the typography and correct all the knit-picky CSS and strategize the design system themselves (not a reasonable option, they don't want to do this anyway).
2. Wait until Chrome implements a DevTools tool that's more sophisticated than basic CSS for ShadowDOM (I don't see this happening anytime soon)
3. Ask on stack-overflow for advice from other similarly frustrated UX engineers.

I'm not here to just hate on Styled-Components, I'm really looking for solutions that fit the encapsulated component dev process that currently ubiquitous in React develoment workflows -- but ALSO is maintainable and malleable in the browser so my job isn't 200x more difficult. My development team agrees, but nobody has a solution.

Comment: use vanilla CSS and DevTools as the IDE ;-/

Comment: This is exactly how I hope the future will return to -- a visual way of affecting visual systems.

Answer (score 0):

A design system is unrelated to css-in-js library. They are concerned with CSS rendering and not providing you with a design system, you will have to use one or build one no matter what rendering engine you use.

What specific problems did you have with debugging solutions you tried? Please provide specific examples with specific issues.

Comment: Of course the design system need to be built, that's my role and comes easily to me -- but we no longer use CSS for it's hierarchical and cascading power so CSS cannot be relied upon for it strengths. Debugging, done within Chrome Dev tools with Styled-Components and babel plug-in is extremely convoluted, meaning one element may take 10 min just to figure out what it is, then requires you to memorize all the obfuscated names and draw links to multiple generated components buried in multiple places in devtools. Quite simply components are designed to be built in isolation and must be styled...

Comment: ...from the ground up, and devtools no longer works to easily manipulate styles.

Comment: Specifically use the devtools selector and click in any component and try to understand its styles and the greater context of the relationship between all the elements. The problem is that establishing, maintaining, and manipulating styles according to a design system are impenetrable from the perspective of how they look and exist in the browser without an unnecessary amount of complexity currently not supported by a devtools feature. It's entirely a workflow issue.

Comment: I would love to see a more concrete example with a link to reproduction and specific steps. Since I maintain JSS, I could tell if same issues exist there, but your description is still too vague for me.

Comment: Can I first ask why generated random class names are used in JSS (and Styled-Components) instead of the unique component names? There are other places that are imperfect -- and I get it, it's not native and is merely a workaround, but it seems it's just there to obfuscate the DOM to no benefit. For the UI developer it's an unnecessary layer abstraction that makes visually manipulating UI components in their visual context more complicated. It's the most frustrating thing I've dealt with in 12 years of dev, and I don't think there's a reason to use random names when unique names already exist.

Comment: Component names are not unique, you would have class name collisions. In DEV mode JSS includes component name in the class name for debugging and makes a shorter one for production. Also JSS accepts a function that you can pass and use your way for generating class names.